# How to capture gesture event in Kinect application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, kinect, gesture-recognition

I have implemented a WPF application, in which I tried to integrate Kinect Gesture Recognition.
I'm using these libraries:

- Microsoft.Kinect
- Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit
- Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Controls
- Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Interaction

When I try to run my application, I can correctly see the hand pointer on the screen, but I don't know how implement event click on the Buttons or Images.

How can I perform this task?

Comment: Are you using KinectTileButton ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you see the hand pointer on the the screen you already have a `KinectRegion` with a connected kinect sensor. Now you can use the [KinectTileButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.toolkit.controls.kinecttilebutton.aspx) or the [KinectCircleButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.toolkit.controls.kinectcirclebutton.aspx). These controls will react when the user extends the hand toward the sensor, indicating a press.

Comment: I have replace Button with KinectTileButton and the applilcation found.Now I should insert a Background Image,so I use this code:<k:KinectTileButton Click="imgCard" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="kinectButton" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" >
                <k:KinectTileButton.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Image x:Name="imgCard"></Image>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </k:KinectTileButton.Template>
            </k:KinectTileButton>

Comment: Why do you set a new control template? When you simply set the content of the button with something like `<k:KinectTileButton><Image x:Name="imgCard"/></k:KinectTileButton>` you are able to access the image directly.